# Why can't I use a Robot Workbench at Boston Airport Ruins?

Tags: fallout-4, fallout-4-automatron

Last weekend, after running through the Automatron DLC, I discovered the Boston Airport Ruins location in Fallout 4 and built a Robot Workbench there.

However, after building it (and leaving Workshop Mode), I found that of the two options, Craft (A button on Xbox) and Transfer (X button), only Transfer was available.

Why is that?

Is it related to the fact that you cannot build a Settlement Beacon radio tower at this location?

Comment: I'd assume that it's because of the limited nature of that settlement. It seems they don't want you to support a full settlement filled with settlers at the Boston Airport based on what they allow you to build, even though they **do** allow you to send settlers there from other settlements. It is curious that they allow you to build the robot workbench there if it is simply unusable... doesn't seem logical to let you create it in the first place.

Comment: Can you mod a robot you bring with you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is embarrassing, but I figured out that it was simply because I was in power armor.

For whatever reason, I was experiencing a bug that made this less obvious than it should have been. The little messages that pop up in the top left? They weren't showing. When something was added to my inventory, for example? Nothing! And the same here. Normally, I would have seen a message, "You can't do that while in Power Armor."

I confirmed that I can craft at this location when not in Power Armor. In fact, I created an absolutely lethal assaultron/robobrain hybrid named Deathsheba, and she is awesome.